# Unexpected Unindent on blank line

Tags: python-2.7

```
def start ():
    print '''Welcome to my game'''
    prompt_1 ()




def prompt_1 ():
    prompt_0 = raw_input('Type a command: ')
    try:
        if prompt_0 == 'go':
            outside_cave ()
        elif prompt_0 == 'help':
            print 'Type "go" to proceed!'
            print
            prompt_1 ()
        else:
            print '...'
            print
            prompt_1 ()


start ()
```

Why do I get an Unexpected Unindent on the blank lines before the start ()

I know that outside_cave () isn't defined, this is a snippet.

Comment: Is the line really blank, or does it have some white space characters on it?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `except` to go with your `try`.  The [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) has an excellent section on Exception Handling that provides examples and other useful information.

Comment: When I try and do that, it gives me another error. It says it is invalid syntax.

Comment: When you try to do what?

Comment: Add the except bit. Can you please give me an example of how I would use it on my piece of code?